# How Should I Write a Scientific Write-up?

Tags: mathematics, writing, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student in mathematics from India. I have been shortlisted in the written test of TIFR GS-2020 (a nationwide entrance), and for the second stage of selection, they are asking for a scientific write-up within 200-250 words. The write-up should particularly address questions such as:

(1) Which particular area in your preferred subject appeals to you most? (2) Are there specific problems you would like to work on? (3) Can you suggest methods to deal with such problems?

Can someone please help me regarding how should I proceed to write this?

Comment: Written in 3rd person singular.

Comment: Go for a walk, come up with some ideas. Sit down; write them down.

Comment: Do the administrators of this test provide any guidance? Can you search on the web for examples of previous year's winners?  I searched briefly but did not find any samples of your letter. I did find previous tests on line.  http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2020/Prev_QP/Prev_QP.htm

Comment: Actually, the question is unclear. Do you want to know what to say? How to go about the writing process? Other?